# Stack Overflow - 'you have reached your question limit'

Tags: support, stack-overflow

I received the following message from Stack Overflow when I try and ask a question:

> You have reached your question limit. 
> Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See the Help Center to learn more.

After reading around on numerous posts, I am still not sure if this is a permanent IP address ban, or if I have a chance at getting my privilege back.

I am new to programming and realize that I shouldn't have deleted some of the questions that I previously asked and that I need to be explicit in the questions that I post. I would love to get the privilege back and am willing to answer other questions to do so. I can't even comment yet as I must have a reputation of 50. I am willing to fix my questions and post answers in hopes of getting the question asking capability back, but I want to make sure this ban isn't permanent first.

[image: img1]

Comment: What does your message say exactly? Can you post a screenshot, or a link to it if you can't post a screenshot?

Comment: I went to post a screenshot, and it looks like my account is now active again! I have been earning badges, answering other questions, and contributing to the community. I take it my ban was not permanent by any means, but I do think StackOverflow needs to distinguish between when the ban is permanent and when users still have the opportunity to earn back their privilege.

Comment: @tccpg288 Before you ask your question, please wait before I post my answer. There are some important things you need to know.

Comment: Thanks, I will certainly wait as I would like to use this forum frequently.

Comment: I hate stack overflow for this reason

Comment: Hello, I would also like to ask questions but I can't anymore. Shame because I'm active on this forum and it helps me a lot. So I tried to help people around here.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I found one question that was worth an upvote. Because you were probably very near the border of the question ban, this put you back outside of the question ban. This means that if your next question is not well-received, you might be question banned again, and it will be much harder to get out of it.

Some things to consider for your next questions:

- You have asked a question and answered it later that day several times. Self-answering is good, but it appears that you just ask a question too fast, without searching and researching enough.
- Do not delete any of your questions. Deleted questions still count for the ban and if there were any answers, they will even count harder against you.

Comment: FYI, [android.se] is *not* for programming questions, unless I missed something (e.g. deleted questions). They should stay on [so].

Comment: @AndrewT. *Other* questions about Android might be on-topic on Android. Have you seen the OP's questions on Stack Overflow?

Comment: Yes, all 8 questions are Android programming questions, which is off-topic on [android.se].

Comment: @AndrewT. Certainly they are not all eight, since one of the questions is about Facebook and nothing more than that. Also, how about this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34756632/android-studio-navigation-error-new-windows-in-background

Comment: The one about Facebook is using Facebook SDK which is programming question. Android Studio is an IDE for Android app development which is also programming question. [android.se] is for Android end-user (consumer, not producer).

Comment: @AndrewT. I think I will trust you on that as you have 4.6k on Android. I removed that part.

Comment: So can I or should I not post android-related programming questions on the Android Enthusiasts page?

Comment: @tccpg288: _Do not_ ask programming questions at [android.se]. They will be closed. The [help center](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) is very clear on that.

Comment: @AlE. Thanks for the heads up. Just trying to make sure my question gets answered, as it is quite technical. Any other references?

Comment: So, self-answering does help one get out of a question ban?

Comment: Also, how do we know how deeply we're questioned-banned?

Comment: This sort of sucks.  I am in the top 33% of posters for this quarter, but deleting old under-viewed questions and asking moderators to delete ones with just a few answers and no votes also won't fix this.  This is very frustrating for those of use who use Stack Overflow regularly.

Comment: Please help me out, I am mostly answering not asking questions and generated many plus points regularly with rarely negatively marked questions still am getting `
You have reached your question limit
Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See the Help Center to learn more.`

Comment: Apparently this is not a good "rule".

Comment: Please also help me... I also have a question ban, but not for a day but since a whole month. How to remove that?? Here's my profile link: https://stackoverflow.com/users/11363434/abhay-salvi?tab=profile  Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: couple of useful links.

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide

https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans

Comment: my stake overflow account was suspended for a month and that's why this appears